# Simple form with React hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

This is very simple, I'm trying to add the input of the form to state, but it's not working. Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-pine-64pxe?file=/src/App.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Field />
      </div>
    );
  }


function Field(){
  const [toDoItem, setToDoItem] = useState("");
console.log(toDoItem)

  const addToDoItem = (event) => {
    setToDoItem(event.target.value)
  }

  return (
        <form >
            <input type="text" value={toDoItem} onChange={addToDoItem}/>
            <input type="submit" value="Add" />
        </form>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: What's it that's *not working* ?

Comment: Everything is working fine as intended. So, what is it that's not working for you?

Comment: I want to be able to type "test" into the input form. Then when I click "Add" I want to see it added to State. I have a console log to display state. Once I click "Add" I want the console.log to display "test"

Answer (score 0):

```
  handleSubmit(event) {
    console.log('Form submitted: ' + toDoItem);
  }
```

Template:-

```
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <input type="text" value={toDoItem} onChange={addToDoItem}/>
            <input type="submit" value="Add" />
    </form>
```